# Using static nested class as generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create an interface with a bounded type parameter, with implementations supplying static nested classes to implement this parameter, as follows:

```
public interface InterfaceProblem<T extends IMyParameter>{
    T getParameterInstance();
}

interface IMyParameter {}

class MyClass implements InterfaceProblem<MyParameter> {
    public MyParameter getParameterInstance() {
        return new MyParameter();
    }

    class MyParameter implements IMyParameter{}
}
```

This gives me a compile error "MyParameter cannot be resolved to a type" on the `MyClass` declaration and its method.  This disappears if I move the static class to its own type:

```
class MyClass implements InterfaceProblem<MyParameter> {
    public MyParameter getParameterInstance() {
        return new MyParameter();
    }
}

class MyParameter implements IMyParameter{}
```

However, I'd like to avoid that, since the MyParameter implementation is closely related to the MyClass implementation.  Is there a better way I can acheive this?  Is this correct compiler behaviour?  (I'm using Eclipse Mars and Oracle jdk1.8.0_60)

Comment: 'static inner' is a contradiction in terms. This is a static nested class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an import:

```
import com.example.MyClass.MyParameter;
```

While the `MyParameter` type is on scope for the `getParameterInstance()` method's return type, it is not for the `MyClass`'s binding of `<T>`